# Skipping blank rows in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape data from 1001TrackLists, a website that lists tracks in DJ mixes, using BeautifulSoup.

If a track is not ID'd in a mix, 1001TrackLists leaves it as 'ID - ID' on the data table which shows up as a blank entry in the scraped code and messes up my for loop.

How do I get Python to skip the "blank" IDs in the track lists and continue scraping data after blank IDs?

My code so far:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'}
page_link  = 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/7mzt0y9/boddika-joy-orbison-rinse-fm-hessle-audio-cover-show-2014-01-16.html'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers)
soup = bs(page_response.content, "html.parser")

tracknumbers = []
tracknames = []
artistnames = []
mixnames = []
dates = []


tracknames_scrape = soup.find_all("div", class_="tlToogleData", div=True)
artistnames_scrape = soup.find_all("meta", itemprop="byArtist")

for (i, track) in enumerate(tracknames_scrape):
    tracknumbers.append(i+1)
    trackname = track.meta['content']
    tracknames.append(trackname)
    print(str(i+1) + str(". ") + trackname)
```

Currently I am able to get all tracks returned until I hit a blank entry, after which I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-de6ecd3caa59> in <module>
      1 for (i, track) in enumerate(tracknames_scrape):
      2     tracknumbers.append(i+1)
----> 3     trackname = track.meta['content']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The script works perfectly if I use a URL that has no blank track IDs.

Comment: I excluded my imports but yes other than that everything here runs as is

Comment: Can you post the stack trace to show where your code is failing

Comment: just add a try expect with continue in the except clause around `trackname = track.meta['content']`. Or you could check the type of track prior to trying to access it something like `if track.meta is not None`

Comment: Add a test before processing the information. Something like `if track.meta:`.

Comment: Can you post the an example of desired output?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but someone else made an [1001tracklists API](https://github.com/yss14/1001tracklist-api).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css selector to get track names.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'}
page_link  = 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/7mzt0y9/boddika-joy-orbison-rinse-fm-hessle-audio-cover-show-2014-01-16.html'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers)
soup = bs(page_response.content, "html.parser")

tracknumbers = []
tracknames = []
artistnames = []
mixnames = []
dates = []


tracknames_scrape =soup.select('div[itemprop="tracks"]>[itemprop="name"]')
#artistnames_scrape = soup.find_all("meta", itemprop="byArtist")

for (i, track) in enumerate(tracknames_scrape):
    tracknumbers.append(i+1)
    trackname = track['content']
    tracknames.append(trackname)
    print(str(i+1) + str(". ") + trackname)
```

**Output**:

```
1. Soft Machine - Snodland
2. Craig Leon - The Customs Of The Age Disturbed
3. Seven Davis Jr. - Thanks
4. Gadi Mizrahi - I'll Set Your House
5. Baby Ford & The iFach Collective - Word For Word
6. Panzer Knacker - Rollin' On The Side Of Psycho
7. 69 - Poi Beats
8. Midi Rain - Shine (DJ Pierre Chicago House Mix)
9. Sunpeople - Check Your Buddha (Sven Väth Remix)
10. Eduardo De La Calle - Madhusudhana
11. Aardvarck - The Antdance
12. Boddika & Joy Orbison - In Here
13. Mike Parker - Lustrations Eight (Contours)
14. Peter Van Hoesen - Axis Mundi
15. Sleeparchive - Bleep 01
16. Conforce - When It Appeared
17. Brommage Dub - Fettwise
18. Matrixxman - Protocol
19. JuJu & Jordash - Powwow
20. Gesloten Cirkel - Yamagic
21. Mike Dehnert - Mischkaa
22. Jerome Sydenham & Joe Claussell - Rhythm
23. Ratchett Traxxx - Nut On U
24. Kenny Dope & Terry Hunter pres. Mass Destruction - No Hook
25. Radio Slave - Don't Stop No Sleep
26. Truncate - Focus
27. Maurizio - Domina (Maurizio Mix Edit)
28. Shed - Atmo - Action
29. AFX - Boxing Day
30. Boddika & Joy Orbison - More Maim
```